# Given $3x+4y=15$, $\min(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})=?$ (looking for other approaches)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, optimization

> Given, $(x,y)$ follow $3x+4y=15$. Minimize $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$.

I solved this problem as follows,
We have $y=\dfrac{15-3x}{4}$,

$$\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=\sqrt{x^2+\frac{(3x-15)^2}{16}}=\frac{\sqrt{25x^2-90x+225}}4=\frac{\sqrt{(5x-9)^2+144}}{4}$$Hence $\min(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})=3$.

I'm wondering is it possible to solve this problem differently?

Comment: $(3x+4y)^2\le (3^2+4^2)(x^2+y^2)$, then $225\le 25(x^2+y^2)$, so $x^2+y^2\ge 9$ implies $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\ge 3$

Comment: @OnTheWay Thanks! May I asked which inequality you used in the first place? Does it have a name?

Comment: It is Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality: https://brilliant.org/wiki/cauchy-schwarz-inequality/

Comment: Let square both sides: $9x^2+24xy+16y^2=225$. Let add inequality $(4x-3y)^2 \geq 0$ to both sides and expand: $25x^2+25y^2 \geq 225$. Let dividy by 25: $x^2+y^2 \geq 9$. Let take square root: $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\geq 3$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image]

$3x+4y=15$  represents a straight line and $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ represents the distance of the point $(x,y)$ from the origin. So the question is basically telling us to find the minimum distance of any point lying on the line $3x+4y=15$, from the origin.

This shortest distance must be the perpendicular distance from the origin to the line.

The perpendicular distance of a point $(h,k)$ from the line $ax+by+c=0$ is $\Bigg|\dfrac{ah+bk+c}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\Bigg|$. Replacing $(h,k)$ with $(0,0)$ and the line with $3x+4y-15=0$ gives us the minimum value as 3.

Answer (score 4):

By [Cauchy-Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality),
$\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\ge\frac{15}{\sqrt{3^2+4^2}}=3$
and by the case of Cauchy-Schwarz equality, this value is attained, hence it is the min you look for.

Answer (score 4):

*Go with Trigonometry.*

Let $x=a\sin \alpha ,\, y=a\cos \alpha$, then we have:
$$\begin{aligned}&3a\sin \alpha+4a\cos \alpha=15\\
\implies &15\leq \sqrt {9a^2+16a^2}=5|a|\\
\implies &|a|\ge 3.\end{aligned}$$

$$\sqrt {x^2+y^2}=|a|\ge 3.$$